# Json parent value with nested children

Tags: javascript, json

I want to create a Json object (in javascript) with multible childeren. But the parent must also have a value, so the code can be executed as:

```
    var parent = {
      "child": {
         "ownValue": "valueChild",
         "grandchild": "ValueGrandChild",
      }
    };
parent.child.grandchild // return "valueGrandChild"
parent.child // return "valueChild"
```

Is this possible in javascript?

Comment: yes it is possible

Comment: oke, can you say how?

Comment: In my opinion we are making stuff hard by our own, things can work easier either. I am not sure what is your code structure, are you looping or manually want to create. But keep only one thing in mind, you have to assign values in such an order so you can get back as you want. Either you use loop or statically assign. Try this one `parent['child'] = 'valuechild';parent['child']['grandchild'] = 'grandvaluechild';` You can use `[` `]` notation in object too

Comment: Looks promising, did you try this code? If i run it in the console i can assign the grandchild value but never access it afterwards.

Comment: yeah for the grandchild, it was not working you are true. I am agree with Eineki

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question (I'm not sure), I would use a different strategy to solve your problem.

As you know, json objects does not have attributes but just children properties. You can use a properties called `child` to store the children objects (the subtree) of your parent object.

```
var parent = {
  "value": "Parent own value",
  "child": {
     "grandchild": {"value": "ValueGrandChild", "child": {}}
     "anotherchild": {"value": "anotherChildValue", "child": {}}
  }
};
```

Children and attributes are better separated and you can address them (and the "proper" object properties) as below:

```
parent.child.grandchild.value // returns "valueGrandChild"
parent.value // returns "Parent own value"
```

You can have also some other *commodities*:

```
var how_many_child = Object.keys(parent.child).length
var a_child = parent.child.anotherchild
var how_many_nephew = Object.keys(a_child.child).length
a_chid.value; // returns "anotherChildValue"
parent.child.anotherchild.value; // returns "anotherChildValue"
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand the question, but you have an error in your formatting of the object at least. It works the way you want if you change the ";" to a ",". (Look below)

Change it from;

```
var parent = {
  "child": {
     "ownValue": "valueChild";
     "grandchild": "ValueGrandChild";
  }
};
```

to;

```
var parent = {
  "child": {
     "ownValue": "valueChild",
     "grandchild": "ValueGrandChild",
  }
};
```

That was you can get the valueChild by using;

```
parent.child.ownValue
```

Comment: fixed the typo.

Answer (score 0):

Even if you did get an object to return another value, you would no longer be able to use that object normally. Every reference to the object would only be referencing the value (invalidating nested object references). You could obviously just keep the "ownValue" property to use for each value you want to tie to an object though.

Comment: Is this possible with another kind of object? like nested functions or something like that?

Comment: @stage-newfish No, everything in JavaScript is either an object or a primitive type. There aren't any special types that would support what you want (if I understand correctly). All primitive types, such as strings, are immutable and as-such cannot be added to or changed. Primitive types are actually copied when assigned.